# If the cookies they are located in client-PC why php can read it?

Tags: php, security, cookies, authentication

Hello Members of the SOF, I would like to know why if the cookies they are located in client-PC why php can read it?

Sample:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["name"])){ }
```

Cookies stay on the client, so how?

Comment: Cookies *don't* stay on the client, they are transmitted in the headers of each HTTP request.

Comment: Did you set any cookies in the first place?

Comment: So, what is the name of the temporary files do sites have ability to store on our computers?

Comment: Or better, for a system of saving passwords, it's best to mix cookies and sessions, and only send the cookie at the next login, and not "at every request".

That's why I asked that question.

Comment: Right ☻ members?